# How to cache the formula cell by using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I created code as below to create excel file and calculate and get cell value after because I need to use function in excel.(this function is not supported by apache poi, so I think I have to read cached./formatted value)

```java
package main;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class WorkbookEvaluator
{
    public static void pop_mean()
    {
        System.out.println ("Test population mean in two different populations are same or not");
        System.out.println ("This program works only for two-tailed ");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("What is population mean?:");
        double m = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("How many samples are taken from population?:");
        double n = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("What is Sample mean?:");
        double X = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("What is unbiased variance for population:");
        double U = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("What is Level of Significance (Type with %-value)");
        double L = in.nextDouble();
        double l = L/100;

            double a = n-1;
            double b = X-m;
            double c = Math.sqrt(n);
            double d = Math.sqrt(U);
            double f = d/c;
            double T = b/f;
            System.out.println ("Degree of freedom is " + a);
            System.out.println ("Test statistic is " + T);

            Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
            Row row1 = sheet.createRow(1);
            Row row2 = sheet.createRow(2);

            Cell cell1_1 = row1.createCell(1);
            Cell cell1_2 = row1.createCell(2);
            Cell cell1_3 = row1.createCell(3);
            Cell cell2_3 = row2.createCell(3);
            Cell cell2_4 = row2.createCell(4);

            cell1_1.setCellValue(l);
            cell1_2.setCellValue(a);
            cell2_3.setCellFormula("_xlfn.T.INV.2T(" + l +"," + a + ")");
            cell2_4.setCellFormula("SUM(" + l +"," + a + ")");

            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream("T-inverse.xlsx");
                wb.write(out);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            } finally {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            }
    }

    public static void read_excel() throws IOException
    {
        for (int q=3;q<5;q++)
        {
            XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook("C:\\Users\\shump\\Java\\Population mean Test\\T-inverse.xlsx");
            book.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
            XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
            sheet.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(2);
            final DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(); 
            final double formtatedValue = row.getCell((short) q).getNumericCellValue(); 
            System.out.println(formtatedValue);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {    
        pop_mean();
        read_excel();
    }
}
```

As can be see from the attempted picture below, it works successfully in excel. However,  consoled output will display 0.0. I thought this is because of function is not supported so I tried same thing by using sum function which is one of the basic function and this function is supported. However, it didn't work. In picture D3 is where I used T.INV.2T function.

[image]

```
Test population mean in two different populations are same or not
This program works only for two-tailed 
What is population mean?:
171.4
How many samples are taken from population?:
9
What is Sample mean?:
172.8
What is unbiased variance for population:
4
What is Level of Significance (Type with %-value)
5
Degree of freedom is 8.0
Test statistic is 2.1000000000000085
0.0
0.0
```

After few research, I found article which states when the formula value is not cached, output will be 0. So, please tell me how I can cache the value or is there any other way that I can take to get value of non-supported function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems misunderstand what `apache poi` is made for. In terms of `Excel` it is made for creating `Excel` files. That meams it creates files which `Excel`is able to open then. When it opens workbook files, it opens them as `apache poi` `Workbook` only to be able to append content. `Apache poi` is not thought to be the same as `Excel` and it does not interact with any `Excel` application.

So the `setForceFormulaRecalculation` is not a `apache poi` setting but a setting for `Excel` when `Excel` opens the workbook. If `setForceFormulaRecalculation` is set `true`, then **Excel** recalculates all formulas when **Excel** opens the workbook file. It does not mean that `apache poi` recalculates all formulas.

To force `apache poi` calculating the formulas, `FormulaEvaluator` needs to be used.

For example if you extend your code as follows:

```
...
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
...
            Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
...
            cell2_4.setCellFormula("SUM(" + l +"," + a + ")");
            try {
                evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell2_4);
            } catch (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException notImplEx) {
                notImplEx.printStackTrace();
            }
...
```

then the `SUM` formula gets evaluated and `cell2_4` contains the evaluated numeric value additional to the formula.

But of course

```
...
            cell2_3.setCellFormula("TINV(" + l +"," + a + ")");
            try {
                evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell2_3);
            } catch (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException notImplEx) {
                notImplEx.printStackTrace();
            }
...
```

will lead to `NotImplementedException` since `TINV` is not yet implemented in `apache poi`.

So we need to do what is shown in [Developing Formula Evaluation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html). In terms of the `TINV` function this would be:

```
...
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.*;
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.TDistribution;
...
    static Function TINV = new Fixed2ArgFunction() {
        public ValueEval evaluate(int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex, ValueEval arg1, ValueEval arg2) {
            try {
                ValueEval ve1 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(arg1, srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex);
                double dArg1 = OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(ve1);
                ValueEval ve2 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(arg2, srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex);
                double dArg2 = OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(ve2);

                TDistribution t = new TDistribution(dArg2);
                double result = t.inverseCumulativeProbability(1d - dArg1/2d);

                if (Double.isNaN(result) || Double.isInfinite(result)) {
                    throw new EvaluationException(ErrorEval.NUM_ERROR);
                }

                return new NumberEval(result);

            } catch (EvaluationException e) {
                return e.getErrorEval();
            }
        }
    };
...
```

and then

```
...
        WorkbookEvaluator.registerFunction("TINV", TINV);
...
```

Note, I have implemented `TINV` instead of `_xlfn.T.INV.2T` since the latter is not able to be implemented that way because of it's strange name. All `Excel` versions I know also support `TINV` instead of `_xlfn.T.INV.2T`.

Complete example extending your code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.*;
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.TDistribution;

public class WorkbookEvaluatorTest {

    static Function TINV = new Fixed2ArgFunction() {
        public ValueEval evaluate(int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex, ValueEval arg1, ValueEval arg2) {
            try {
                ValueEval ve1 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(arg1, srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex);
                double dArg1 = OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(ve1);
                ValueEval ve2 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(arg2, srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex);
                double dArg2 = OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(ve2);

                TDistribution t = new TDistribution(dArg2);
                double result = t.inverseCumulativeProbability(1d - dArg1/2d);

                if (Double.isNaN(result) || Double.isInfinite(result)) {
                    throw new EvaluationException(ErrorEval.NUM_ERROR);
                }

                return new NumberEval(result);

            } catch (EvaluationException e) {
                return e.getErrorEval();
            }
        }
    };

    public static void pop_mean() {

        WorkbookEvaluator.registerFunction("TINV", TINV);

        System.out.println ("Test population mean in two different populations are same or not");
        System.out.println ("This program works only for two-tailed ");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("What is population mean?:");
        double m = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("How many samples are taken from population?:");
        double n = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("What is Sample mean?:");
        double X = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("What is unbiased variance for population:");
        double U = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("What is Level of Significance (Type with %-value)");
        double L = in.nextDouble();
        double l = L/100;

        double a = n-1;
        double b = X-m;
        double c = Math.sqrt(n);
        double d = Math.sqrt(U);
        double f = d/c;
        double T = b/f;
        System.out.println ("Degree of freedom is " + a);
        System.out.println ("Test statistic is " + T);

        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
        Row row1 = sheet.createRow(1);
        Row row2 = sheet.createRow(2);

        Cell cell1_1 = row1.createCell(1);
        Cell cell1_2 = row1.createCell(2);
        Cell cell1_3 = row1.createCell(3);
        Cell cell2_3 = row2.createCell(3);
        Cell cell2_4 = row2.createCell(4);

        cell1_1.setCellValue(l);
        cell1_2.setCellValue(a);
        cell2_3.setCellFormula("TINV(" + l +"," + a + ")");
        try {
            evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell2_3);
        } catch (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException notImplEx) {
            notImplEx.printStackTrace();
        }

        cell2_4.setCellFormula("SUM(" + l +"," + a + ")");
        try {
            evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell2_4);
        } catch (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException notImplEx) {
            notImplEx.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream("T-inverse.xlsx");
            wb.write(out);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Write: " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();
                wb.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Close: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void read_excel() throws IOException {
        for (int q=3;q<5;q++) {
            XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook("T-inverse.xlsx");
            //book.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
            XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
            //sheet.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(2);
            final DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(); 
            final double formtatedValue = row.getCell((short) q).getNumericCellValue(); 
            System.out.println(formtatedValue);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {    
        pop_mean();
        read_excel();
    }
}
```